# Calling a stored procedure with sequelize and an express API

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

This is probably pretty easy but I've been unable to piece it together properly.

I'm trying to use the Sequelize NPM to call a stored procedure that I built and then I want to trigger it with a GET request from from an express api and return the output of the procedure to the api.

Here is what my code looks like for the Sequelize portion....

```
// Testing stored procedure //
   const Retrieve = (testName) => connection.testdata_connection.query("EXEC [SPROC] [INPUTS]")

   module.exports = {
       tests: Tests(),
       retrieve: Retrieve()
    };
```

This part "connection.testdata_connection" is just establishing my connection to the database and I have tested this and I know this part is set.

I would like to be able to hit that with something like...

```
const query = require('./database/queries');  ///Imports sequelize queries

const app = express();

app.get('/decrypt', function(req,res){
    query.retrieve()
    })
   
})
```

This doesn't work at all.

Now if I do something like this in the queries file...

```
    const Retrieve = async function() {
        const decrypt = await connection.testdata_connection.query("EXEC [SPROC] [INPUT]")
        console.log(decrypt)
    }
   module.exports = {
       tests: Tests(),
       retrieve: Retrieve()
    };
```

This will log to my console with correct data when I start the server. I want it to do that when I hit it with my endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your function should be exported but not executed:

```
   // creating an async function (all i/o operations should be async).
   const Retrieve = async(testName) => connection.testdata_connection.query("EXEC [SPROC] [INPUTS]")

   module.exports = {
       retrieve: Retrieve,
       // retrieve: Retrieve() if you call the function with (), the function will be executed and we don't want that yet
    };
```

Now we can call it in the route:

```
const query = require('./database/queries');  ///Imports sequelize queries

const app = express();
// the route is async because it is executing async code
app.get('/decrypt', async (req,res) => {
    // waiting for the answer with await
    const response = await query.retrieve();
    // Doing something with the response
})
```

You still need to check for errors, but that is the basics.

Comment: I appreciate this. You bridged a gap in my understanding and saved me a good chunk of time. Thank you.